# Is there are cooling pad for laptop that works only when necessary?

Tags: laptop, cooling, cooling-pad, laptop-cooler

Usually cooler's fans work all the time, but I wonder if there are pads with temperature sensors, that will turn on fan when necessary.

Comment: If your laptop is overheating to the point it is shutting itself down, a cooling pad, really isn't going to help prevent that.  A laptop shouldn't overheat.  At best your talking 2-3 degrees cooler, a CPU is going to still throttle itself at that point.

Comment: @Ramhound temperature of laptop is ok, but fan is loud and sound is nasty and works always (its such model of laptop), so I want to remove bottom of the laptop's corpus and may be top of the cooling pad and use the pad instead of internal cooler (which I will plug out), I have AMD.

Comment: That is a horrible idea.  A cooling pad WILL NOT provide enough cooling, you WILL damage your CPU, if it does not have active cooling.  Proceed with extreme caution and complete disregard to the health of your hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure? Because: fan inside laptop blows at radiator, not right at processors. And I want big fan that will blow right at processors.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment says....."small cooler that winds at radiator" does not make logical sense.

Comment: @Ramhound improved

Comment: Just blowing semi-warm air at a CPU won't do very much, the radiator works, because it draws the heat away from the CPU.  Go ahead and do what you plan to do, just be prepared, it will overheat instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The Thermaltake Massive says it has temperature sensors.  I don't personally own one so I don't know how accurate the thing is:  http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00002129